# Register variable storage class error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, macros, c-preprocessor

Kindly help me with this error:

> error: storage class specified for 'interrupt_save_disabled'
>        #define TX_INTERRUPT_SAVE_AREA                  register unsigned int interrupt_save_disabled;

This is a header file in which it is used:

```
#if defined (WIN32) || defined (LINUX)
#define register
#endif
  TX_INTERRUPT_SAVE_AREA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `register` on a global variable. Remove the specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `register`. It's pointless.